# How to solve a datatype mismatch error in VB6?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, adodb, type-mismatch

I have declared `DR_DATE` field as date in transaction table (MS Access). Now,

```vb
Set RS1 = New ADODB.Recordset
RS1.Open "select * from transaction where DR_DATE < '#" + CDate(Text_date.Text) + "#'", CN1, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

is showing datatype mismatch error... what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try without single quotes before/after # and format Text_date.Text to US format mm/dd/yyyy

```
RS1.Open "select * from transaction where DR_DATE < #" & Format(CDate(Text_date.Text),"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#", CN1, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: You may need the ISO sequence for the date format for ADO: `yyyy-mm-dd`.